# iOS deeplink works on one devices but not working on other

Tags: ios, branch.io, deeplink

I've encountered a problem with deeplinks when testing them on several devices. I've found out that deeplinks works properly on ones of them(i.e. redirect to the app exactly) but on the others they redirect to AppStore.
I've read the Branch's troubleshooting guide about this issue(link below) saying that this problem may be caused by explicit prohibition of app links when pressing the button on the upper right corner of status bar.
And I've read that it can be fixed by long pressing the link from the Note app and then clicking "Open in App" button.

But the problem is that there is no such a button at all although the app is installed on device.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdSq7.png)

P.s: I know that my universal links are fully configured and working because as I said deeplinks work properly on several devices and the same button(Open in App) appears in the Note app for these devices.

https://support.branch.io/support/solutions/articles/6000153326-ios-universal-links-troubleshooting-guide

Comment: where is your actual deeplink, btw? the screenshot shows a standard `https://` link, and such links are supposed to open Safari on iOS.

Comment: but it opens in my app on other devices

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the solution. When I add my URL scheme that I register on dashboard to my project's info.plist. I started being redirected correctly. But it didn't fix the issue with unemerging 'Open in app' button when long press link. And I cannot block app links. because there is no button in the status bar.
As for devices where deeplinks had worked initially they haven't broken. I still can block app links for these devices and 'Open in app' button appeares.

Answer (score 0):

Amruta from [Branch.io](http://branch.io) here:

If you are facing issues with Universal links configuration, our team has a validation tool that allows us to check various information about your Xcode project configuration to make sure everything is configured properly.

Once the configuration information is collected, the script sends it to Branch and returns a short-link you can follow to view the validation results. For exact instructions on running the script, I'd like to point you to the relevant docs page, found here:
https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-linking-validator/

as well as the validator, which can be found here:
https://branch.io/resources/universal-links/

After running the local script, open the link in your web browser and enter your Branch Key and Secret to view the test results.

If you still continue to face issues I would suggest writing into `integrations@branch.io` and we'll walk through your integration with you!